# Most efficient way to determine common elements count across large lists of integers

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a `List<List<int>>` to which i continuously add new `List<int>`. But before adding i need to make sure my new list contains **less than *n*** integers that are common to other `List<int>` in my main list. In other words, no duplicates by taking in consideration a **minimum of *n*** elements.

So if my first list contains { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } and my second list { 1, 3, 2, 6, 4 } - this would be a duplicate if ***n* = 4**

I used `.Intersect()` and got the `.Count()` while looping through the whole list but that gets really slow when the dataset is larger.

What other efficient options do i have here for checking for these duplicates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Traversing large lists can be slow, especially if your are traversing multiple large lists.  The speed of checking for the existence of each element of the new list in all of the lists is essentially O (n * k) where n is the sum of the count of all existing lists and k is the number of items in the new list.

You can solve the speed issue in several different ways, but if you don't have very tight memory limitations, I think my choice would be to use an additional HashSet to store a list of items already in any list and look up the new items in that HashSet.  A HashSet takes exactly one operation to find an item, regardless of the size of the HashSet... making it super fast for this kind of lookup.

```
Algorithm for this:
1) Get new List to add to List of List
2) Validate that the new list is new enough by:
    A)  Checking the HashSet for .Contains() on each item of the new list
    B) Check that no more than the allowed number of items already exist
3) Add the new List to the list of lists
4) Add each of the items of the new list to the HashSet
```

My assumption here is that you don't care which existing list contains that Int and that it can appear in as many lists as you want as long as each new list doesn't exceed its quote

Comment: Agreed, except step 4, only add the non existing items into the Hashset. Better, create a new Hashset (called newItems) and add items into it if step 2.A returns false. At step 4, concatene the 2 hashsets.

Comment: @MartinVerjans, definitely a good point.  However, I prefer the simplicity and readability of not creating an extra HashSet and feel the performance penalty will tiny, as the HashSet will prevent an actual duplicate add in any case, so it is just the cost of checking existence again.  In my opinion, clean code wins in this case over a minor performance benefit... but that is an issue of style.